# chrome.sockets API tcp error codes?

Tags: sockets, tcp, google-chrome-app, error-code

I'm developping a HTTP serveur as a Chrome App but I don't know how to interpret error codes caught in:

```
chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceiveError.addListener( (info) => 
  console.error( "Error on Receive: socket=%s, resultCode=%s", info.socketId, info.resultCode )
)
```

Sometimes I get the following error with `info.resultCode = -100` (when the connection is timed out).

I've found some Unix/Sockets codes but they don't seem to match, and I found nothing on Google's [Chrome App](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network) Dev website.

[This one](https://gist.github.com/gabrielfalcao/4216897) and [this one](http://www.workers.com.br/manuais/53/html/tcp53/mu/mu-7.htm) could match but I'm not sure.
For example, with that [commented error list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/819124), I can guess the `error 10064` is corresponding to my `-100 resultCode`.

Can someone direct me to the right documentation?

Comment: Please explain your latest tag edit.

Comment: @Xan I beleive it can concern Chrome Extension developers too.

Comment: It cannot: `chrome.sockets` is only available in Apps

Comment: @Xan I know. I was speaking about Extension developers, not extensions.

Comment: @Xan Why do you delete the tcp tag ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like there is a list of them defined in [net_error_list.h](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/net/base/net_error_list.h&sq=package:chromium&l=111)